# Return all rows that have at least one reference with all the rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to apologize for the title but I couldn't think of a more suitable/accurate one (English is not my first language)

How can I return all persons that caught at leas one fish from all species?

Here is my database: [image]

From the schema above I should return only the person with ID 1

Comment: Please don't post a random link for "your database". Put the DDL and DML in your question.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specify that this is a dummy/test database

Comment: Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. TL;DR:
Please include sample data and expected output as well as your initial attempt and where are you getting problems/errors at.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way by comparing distinct number of captured species per person to the total number of species:

```
SELECT ID_person
FROM capture  c
GROUP BY c.ID_person
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.Id_species) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM species)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM species s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM captures c
        WHERE 
            c.ID_species = s.ID_species
            AND c.ID_person = p.ID_person
    )
)
```

The operation you are asking for is called [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)).

The sentence "give me all persons that have at least one capture for each specie" can be rewriting as "give me all persons that doesn't exist any specie with no captures" this is where NOT EXISTS comes into play